# Mysql - Left Join all tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT 'asdf', '123' ...
FROM table1

LEFT JOIN table2
on
(
    condition1
)

LEFT JOIN table3
on
(
    condition2
)

where
(
    main_condition
)
```

Now the problem is, I need to conditionally include `table1` as well. I tried this:

```
..
..
FROM table1
on
(
    new_condition
)
..
..
```

but it wouldn't work. Please help.

---

**EDIT** (New finding):
In this post (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/20/sql-server-select-from-dual-dual-equivalent/), I found this piece of code:

```
SELECT 1 as i, f.bar, f.jar FROM dual LEFT JOIN foo AS f on f.bar = 1 WHERE dual.dummy = ‘X’
UNION
SELECT 2 as i, f.bar, f.jar FROM dual LEFT JOIN foo AS f on f.bar = 2 WHERE dual.dummy = ‘X’
```

I'm sure it's not directly related to what I'm trying to do, but is it possible to `JOIN` a table to `DUAL` like that?

Comment: You mean use a `where table1.foo = ???`? If table1 is optional, then it shouldn't be on the left-hand side of a left join operation.

Comment: maybe it's just me, but I have no idea what you're asking for help with.  your main select has a from table1 left join table2 on condition which by it's nature includes all records from table one and only those that match on table2.  Depending on the "ON" Clauses, you're already including all records from table1.  Are you saying you only want a subset of table 1 records?  if so then the where clause or ON criteria can limit it further...  sample data/and expected result would help me here.

Comment: @xQbert It's actually this: I want to select rows from table1 only if `new_condition` is true

Comment: But yet you still want to select from the other tables if `new_condition` is false?  Then it sounds to me like you don't want a `LEFT JOIN`... see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Just put that in the where clause.  you don't need it on the join since you're including all records from table 1 to begin with.  So in essence you're returning everything from t1 where T1.new_condtion=True and including all matching recrds in T2 and maybe t3, depending on the ON clause if it joins back to T1 or though T2.

Comment: What if there are *no* matching rows in `table1`? I still want `table2` and `table3` to be joined, depending on the respective conditions

Comment: *Please see my EDIT on the question*

Comment: I'm confused about what results you want so sample data and expected result would help the most.  based on comments thus far I think you want All data from table 2 and matching data from table 3 and matching data from table 1 that matches data in table 2 which would make table 1 a right join from table 1 to table two instead of a left.  this is a SET logic problem which the following diagrams may help you understand. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for contributing to the discussion. I found the answer. It's really simple:

```
SELECT temp_table.* FROM
    (SELECT 'asdf', '123' ... FROM DUAL) temp_table
LEFT JOIN table1
on
(
    new_condition
)

LEFT JOIN table2
on
(
    condition1
)

LEFT JOIN table3
on
(
    condition2
)

where
(
    main_condition
)
```

Interesting problem. Maybe I should favorite my own question this time :)

Answer (score 3):

**Dummy table:**

Select a record from a dummy table first. `dual` is such a table, that is built in in MySQL for this exact purpose. I wrapped `dual` in a subselect, because MySQL apparently doesn't allow left joining against it.

```
SELECT 'asdf', '123' ...
FROM 
  (select 1 from dual) d
LEFT JOIN table1
on(
  new_condition
)
LEFT JOIN table2
on
(
    condition1
)

LEFT JOIN table3
on
(
    condition2
)
```

**Full (outer) join**

Another solution, though different is using a `full join` or `full outer join`, which is like a `left join` and `right join` combined. It is quite different, though you can achieve a very similar result:

```
select
  *
from
  table1
  full outer join table2 on joincondition.
```

In the query above, all records from both tables are returned, even if no matching record in either table exists.

Comment: _copied from below:_ That doesn't work, because the whole query will fail if the where condition fails - even if condition1 and condition2 are true

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood. Changed it to a different solution.

Comment: I've tried this. It doesn't work. Would've been perfect if it did :)

Comment: Any errors? It should work. Maybe dual needs an alias, although I don't think so.

Comment: Added `full outer join`, which could also solve your problem, depending on the join conditions you have. It's hard to tell without more concrete information.

Comment: This is the error: `.. expected END_OF_INPUT or ';'`. Full outer join is not what I require, sorry :(

Comment: Apparently in MySQL you cannot left join agains dual directly. I've made a minor change (put a select around `dual` to which the other tables are joined. This construct I just tested and works.

Comment: I've already posted an answer. It's very similar to this. Thanks

Comment: Re *"because MySQL apparently doesn't allow left joining against it."* **Why** does MySQL not allow `dual` joins? Is there any reason at all?

Comment: @Pacerier `dual` is not an actual table, but a fake table that can be used to select constant values. MySQL supports it to be somewhat compatible with Oracle, but apparently they just didn't implement joining on it like this. I don't think there is a real reason against it. It's just not built (yet).

Answer (score 0):

you cant make this new condition in ON clause

on clause is just when you join, but you can add this new condition in where clause

example

```
    where
 (
main_condition
 )
  AND
 (
  new condition 
 )
```

EDIT:

try this

```
 SELECT 'asdf', '123' ...
 FROM (select 'asdf', '123' ... FROM table1 WHERE new_condition ) t
                                                      ^^--your new condition here
 LEFT JOIN table2
 on
 ........
```

EDIT2:  if your new condition can be wrong you can make an if statment

```
    where
  (
 main_condition
 )
 AND
 (
  if(new condition is something , do something , else do something else) 
 )
```

edit3:

```
 SELECT 'asdf', '123' ...
 FROM (select 'asdf', '123' ... FROM table1 where main condition
       UNION 
      select 'asdf', '123' ... FROM table1 WHERE new_condition ) t
                                                  ^^--your new condition here
 LEFT JOIN table2
 on
 ........
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because the whole query will fail if the where condition fails - even if `condition1` and `condition2` are true

Comment: That doesn't change anything, does it? Again, if `new_condition` fails, `t` is empty. The query won't return anything

Comment: when you join use t as table as i made an alias

Comment: What I meant is, if `new_condition` is false and all other conditions are true, I still want `table2` and `table3` to be joined. In your case, if `new_condition` is false, `select 'asdf', '123' ... FROM table1 WHERE new_condition` returns nothing, which means the alias `t` is empty. That fails the whole query, as you're trying to `JOIN` `t`

Comment: then it will be wwith IF statment or CASE statment , if you post your quiery we can look at it

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't - stupid policies. The query isn't much different from what I've posted in the question, though. You wouldn't possibly get anything extra outta it.

Comment: I don't see what that can achive. If `new_condition` isn't true, I want `table1` to be *not* joined and all other tables to be joined (depending on their respective conditions). How can this achieve that? Whatever comes inside the where determines the success of the whole query, not just `table1`

Comment: you can use a union , so if the first query fail then the second query in union will execute

Comment: check my edit3 , i think now you can do it via union if the condition fails then first query will load and vise versa and if two right they will load both

Comment: You just wrote 2 queries for something that can be done in one :)

Comment: I've found a perfect solutions that works. Please see my answer

Comment: ok nice you got the answer , but maybe my last answer  can help you

Comment: Hope so, @echo_Me. I'll deffly test that one once I get this thing running :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the condition in the `on` clause for the first join:

```
SELECT 'asdf', '123' ...
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     on condition1 AND new condition LEFT JOIN
     table3
     on condition2
where main_condition
```

When using a `where` clause with `left join` be careful.  Normally, you want to move these conditions into the `on` clauses, because they can inadvertently undo the effect of the left outer join (turning it into an `inner join`).

Comment: If `condition1` is true and all other conditions (except `main_condition`) are false, the query should still return `table2`. In your query, that doesn't work

Comment: *Please see my EDIT on the question*

Comment: i think you should use OR in `on condition1 AND new condition` because new condition he said can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

My best guess with comments to date.

```
SELECT 'asdf', '123' ...
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2  --NOTE THE FULL OUTER here  all records in table 2 and only those that match in table 1
on
    condition1 AND
    new_condition=True
LEFT JOIN table3
on
(
    condition2
)

where
(
    main_condition
)
```